# Does this prepositional phrase need commas?

Tags: punctuation

Which one of the following is best?:

1. Notice how on the surface he looks like he hasn't stolen anything.
2. Notice how, on the surface, he looks like he hasn't stolen anything.

Answer (score 0):

Both are bad for different reasons.

In direct answer to your question - yes, the commas are needed. The phrase "on the surface" is *nonrestrictive*, or non-essential. In other words, you could omit it entirely and the sentence would still make complete sense. However, this phrase doesn't sound right at all in this context, which is why I don't think either are correct. Even if it is grammatical, it isn't quite logical.

"On the surface" is an idiom that means "*superficially; considering only the obvious details or outward appearance of someone or something*". So, it *can* refer to the outward 'surface' of a *person*, suggesting that their outward appearance belies something within. But I don't see how this could apply to knowing that someone has stolen something. You'd normally say it in relation to some inner personality flaw that may at times be visible, for example:

> On the surface he seems nice, but he can be mean.

I think you may be wanting to refer to the *situation* or the available *evidence* that would indicate him having stolen something. And the situation isn't the person.

You could say:

> Notice how, on the surface, **it** looks like he hasn't stolen anything.

"It" can refer to the situation.

Comment: I agree with that last one (and the others) but you never go for what an OP has said. This: Notice how, on the surface, he looks like he hasn't stolen anything. is fine.

Answer (score -1):

The 2nd is better because, arguably, the 1st could be parsed as "Notice how[,] on the surface [**that**] he looks like[,] he hasn't stolen anything.

Comment: Very arguably. There are probably examples where this would be something to consider.

Comment: It's because 'like' can be either a preposition or a conjunction (combined with a copular verb 'look').

Comment: You would lose points on TOEFL or in high school English for using commas as in (2).  It's incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

(2) is incorrect.

Do not use commas to offset essential elements of the sentence.  A clause is "essential" if you cannot remove it without breaking the sentence or changing the meaning of the surrounding words.

Compare:

"Notice how, he looks like he hasn't stolen anything." (incorrect!)

"**Notice how, now that he's concealed the package, he looks like he hasn't stolen anything.**" (correct)

That said, this is a slightly odd use of "on the surface" and both because it is odd, and because it is unnecessary, you should just write:

"**Notice how he looks like he hasn't stolen anything.**"